# Is it possible to see how your html & css code would look on a mobile device without actually have a website url?

Tags: html, css, testing, mobile, tablet

I have a project to do and I am desperate for a site that would show me how a mobile website would look with the code I have. The problem is i don't have a website url that I can use it on that will show the images provided with it.

Thanks,

Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use emulation feature of Google Chrome. Open your web page and hit `Ctrl+Shift+J` to open dev tools. There, click on a "drawer" icon (third from the right) - it will open the drawer panel. There, use "Emulation" tab - it will allow you to select from different various devices. Chrome will emulate screen resolution, input, and User Agent string.

Comment: Good answer, I've used the emulator with some success too. It's a nice feature, but i found it to be buggy, I prefer to use [Opera Mobile Emulator](http://dev.opera.com/articles/opera-mobile-emulator/)

Comment: Great answers from everyone really, I never knew such emulators existed! It's saving me A LOT of time! Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

Take the page on your desktop and resize the window to resemble the size of a mobile device. Pretty much you are making the window the same pixel size of a mobile phone's browser.

As far as the pictures go, you would need a url. You may be able to use this
http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

In firefox you can use the responsive design layout using the command  " ctrl+shif+m " .

This comes configured with default ranges for devices.

You can also install "web developer tool" in firefox and chrome . It has a  "resize" tool that will show your page in mobile and tablet views also .